# Not able to retrieve BrandingSet thru Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api

Not able to retrieve BrandingSet (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_brandingset.htm) thru Metadata API

package.xml that I used to retrieve BrandingSet thru workbench:

[image]

BrandingSets in my Org is not retrieved.

Any insights on why I am not able to retrieve Branding Sets from my Org?

Comment: do you meet the criteria in the [metadata api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_brandingset.htm?search_text=brandingset)

Comment: I was able to retrieve Network (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_network.htm) metadata type successfully.
But unsuccessful for BrandingSet metadata (configured branding set within a Network)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've specified the API version as 46.0 in the package.xml.
It would also be worth checking which version of the Metadata API you are working against for the actual calls.

According to the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/47) [BrandingSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/47/BrandingSet/details) was first exposed in Winter '19 v44.0 for the Metadata API.

Winter '20 v47.0 will expand the support for Managed Packaging.

[image]